# Bottom layers print fine, then infill and wall layers instantly fail

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, creality-slicer

I have an Ender 3 V2 which I use together with Creality slicer. I print in PLA at 200 °C. The print bed is set to 60 °C. The layer height I set to 0.2 mm. Print speed is set to 50 mm/s.

Printing on an Ender 3 V2, the bottom layers of the print I am attempting work fine, but as soon as the printer starts printing the infill it starts printing little balls of filament instead of the infill. Not sure what the issue is as this has never been an issue before, but this started happening after replacing my empty filament roll with a new one, the same PLA as before. Using the same print settings as I have for many successful previous prints.

How can I fix this?

The image is the bottom of a print

I printed a Benchy, but it looks pretty ugly.

Also noticed an erratic squeaking from the motor, not sure if that’s the cause or what I would do if it is.

After cleaning the bed and getting a perfect bottom print, the infills still won’t come out right.

Also tried doing some cold pulls to clean the nozzle and slow the print speed down to 30 mm/s but it still will not print infills well. Would love to hear some input.

After tightening the screw giving tension to the filament, the squeaking turned into thumping. I attached the youtube link where you can hear it in the first 15 seconds of the video on an extrusion.
https://youtube.com/shorts/pIZ7TYW5NlU?feature=share

[image: Photo of the top of the extruder on an Ender 3v2]

[image: Photo of the Z endstop on an Ender 3v2]

[image: Photo of a 3D model with the infill not being extruded properly]

Comment: In the photo, is that the top or bottom of the print?

Comment: Can we get a photo from the side? Are your Z steppers working okay?

Comment: The bottom layers aren't fine, they also look underextruded. We need more information to help you. I have inserted a hidden template, please [edit] your question and fill out the  template and remove the <!-- and --> to reveal the information in the question. We are particularly interested in the material, the temperature and the printing speed for instance. Thanks!

Comment: What's your actual question? It's best to reflect that in the title as well.

Comment: As a first step, try slowing down the print speed closer to 60.

Comment: Is your hotend cooling fan working properly? Could be heat creep leading to blockages and the extruder slipping.

Comment: @BobOrtiz - IMHO the title (probably) reflects the issue adequately. However, changing it into a (grammatically correct) title, such as "How can I fix my instantly failing infill and wall layers, even though bottom layers print fine?" just seems to add fluff, which (arguably) makes it harder to *immediately* see the issue (by a few seconds). I don't think every title *has* to be a question, does it? So long as the issue is clear, that is the main thing.

Comment: @Greenonline, I respectfully disagree. I read the current title and think 'so?'. It's just ambiguous what the user wants to achieve. In such posts one always needs to actually read the whole post, all text before maybe getting a slight idea. Which sometimes is lacking even a question in the body. It's annoying, when I scroll feeds I want to understand the question directly, it's a QA site. QA should say it all. Because if the question interests me, I'll maybe answer. But with such posts you need to read it all before you can decide if it even interesting. Very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

These sort of questions are hard to answer without having the hardware present. As such, this answer focusses on the observations posted in the question. A troubleshooting could help find the actual problem, and could be put into an answer as well.

#### Observations

By looking at the supplied images (one image in the first post), your printer is underextruding, even the bottom layers do not look good, they also are underextruded. You can see the layer under the top layer:

[image]

Your cold-pull actions have helped a little, the effect is less seriously present:

[image]

Quoting:

> Also noticed an erratic squeaking from the motor, not sure if that’s the cause or what I would do if it is.

#### Troubleshooting aid

You should troubleshoot the extruder. It looks as if the frame is littered with small pieces of filament debris that could potentially be grinding debris. Grinding will reduce the amount of filament being extruded with under extrusion as result. Furthermore, check the whole extrusion path if filament can be extruded without too much force. You could decouple/bypass the extruder and feed the Bowden tube manually with a hotend at the correct temperature for your filament. If there is a lot of friction, investigate where this comes from.

Comment: The mess on the frame is just spaghetti from a failed print. And after doing the manual push with the Bowden tube, I do not feel a lot of resistance.